# only open child webpage if it is no longer open or the url changed to a different site?

Tags: javascript, url, html, reload

I do not want the webpage to reload if its already open, as this causes unnecessary data to be sent to the javascript application.

If the webpage is not open, I want it to be open.
If the webpage was open but the user used teh tab to load another webpage, i want a new webpage to open,.

If the webpage is open and still on the right url, I do not want any change, I do not want it to refresh.

However I can not seem to find a way to know if the url changed.

I can use cookies if i have to but would rather not. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: ps im using javascript and window.open to open the window.

Comment: [don't... don't do that...](https://sendgrowth.com/assets/img/blog/pop-up-meme.jpg)